# Step by Step install of wso2 EMM for Ubuntu

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've visited the wso2 website and the install instructions are very disjointed in that there is a lot of jumping around between pages.  I've seen the following blog that seemed to streamline the instructions but it doesn't seem complete (plus it's out of date with the version it's installing) - https://maxmalm.se/blog/2014-06-17-installing-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager-110

Has anyone seen step-by-step instructions on what needs to be done to completely setup wso2-EMM on a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine with just the O/S on it and none of the pre-reqs installed yet?  The blog I mentioned above seems to give a lot of the necessary apt-get install bits but doesn't mention anything about a database (yet the wso2 has a whole section on installing and using a database).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To try out WSO2 EMM you will only need to have JDK 7 or 8 [1] installed as minimum to start off the server. WSO2 products are build to run with OOB database which is H2. So to get things started and play around, I suggest that you install java and then start the pack to get things going.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Installing+on+Linux+or+OS+X

Comment: So I don't need to install a database then.  That would explain the blog post I found that didn't mention a database install.  Thank you for this reply.  I will give this a try.

Comment: H2 databases are included in the server. so you do not want to install any separate DB servers when running the product. But if you are going for production it is not recommended to use H2 databases.

Answer (score 0):

To getting started all you need is JDK installed in your machine and setting the Java related environment variables like PATH, JAVA_HOME. You might have to install the correct version of JDK for the particular version of the EMM.